# Input with spaces

Tags: c, input, struct, linked-list

So i was trying to make a function for searching... i have a struct like this which saves to a file and reads it whenever i want to...

```
 struct Entry{
        char title[100];
        char author[100];
        char series[100];
        char genre[100];
        struct Entry* next;
    };
```

Each struct Entry *ptr is linked by a linked list, so whenever i want to search i can easily do it...

The problem is i want my input to be [struct variable][space][substring]

for example, if i want to search for all titles with the word tree in it the input should be "title tree" ... how can i do this?, im thinking of scanf("%s %s") (though i know its dumb to do that) but what if the user inputs more than a word?... can anyone help me?

Comment: Some real code, please. And I don't get your question. Is this question just about how to use `scanf` properly?

Comment: Use `fgets()` for user input: unlike `scanf()` it has a sane treatment of errors.

Comment: i have edited my question... sorry i dont know what happened... well if i use fgets, the problem is... it will scan the file till new line... while in my code... i want to scan two things in one line... the first word being the struct variable and the second one: substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can scan more than one word with scanf, however

> there are better ways to scan without using `scanf`

but if you persist to use `scanf`, use it this way:

```
scanf("%[^\n]",string);
```

also see this for more information: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555108/multiple-word-string-input-through-scanf)

Comment: thanks!... i think it worked... i did it like scanf("%s %[^\n]",inp1,inp2)

and it is reading the first word as inp1 and the second string as inp2 

is there a better way?... but it looks fine to me!...

thanks!!!

Comment: Mark as answer if it helped :)@ClarenceGabrielRazonKasilag