# I can´t print a string that was read using the "gets" function

Tags: c

It works if I read the string value first and then the int value.
I tried use function `gets` instead of `scanf` because `gets` lets me read more than one word in the same line.

I also tried with `fgets` but it has the same problem.

I'm using cygwin 32 bit compiler version 2.874. I using codeblocks ide 13.12.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char s[10];

    printf("Value int:\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("%d\n",i);

    printf("Value string:");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(s);
    printf("%s\n",s);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not use gets . Use instead fgets ==> fgets(s, 10, stdin); or scanf ==> scanf("%9s", s);

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555108/multiple-word-string-input-through-scanf

Comment: `gets` is not standard (anymore) and every toolchain should yell at you using it one way or the other. **Never ever** use it! And `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behaviour. Also don't use it!

Comment: `scanf` can read more than one word in one line too, if using correctly. And which IDE you are using is insignificant, while the compiler may concerns, and `cygwin` is not a compiler.

Comment: See [Why the `gets()` function is to dangerous to be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) for a discussion of why you should not use it and what the alternatives are.  You also need to check the return results.  You should look at [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) for a discussion about why that is to be used with caution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the call to `scanf`, a newline is left in the input buffer.  So when you call `gets`, just that newline gets picked up.

Calling `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior as per the C standard, although MSVC supports it as an extension.  You should instead use `getchar` to read the newline from the buffer.

Comment: Using 'getchar' after call  'scanf' and before call 'gets' was very useful.
Thanks!.

Comment: I followed your advices so I used fgets.

    printf("Value int:\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("%d\n",i);
    getchar(); // This line was very useful.
    printf("Value string:");
    fgets (s , sizeof s , stdin);
    printf("%s\n",s);

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The second input will take the new line when you input the integer, try this with `scanf`:

```
scanf(" %s", s); // here the space will emit the previous newline or space
```

or better to use `fgets` which will limit the input to the size of the buffer:

```
fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);
```

Also, do not use `gets`, it is dangerous and subject to buffer overflow. And do not call `fflush` on `stdin`, `stdin` is an input stream, flushing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: `gets` is not deprecated, but not even part of the C standard library.

Comment: @Olaf It was part of C89 and C99, and removed in C11.

Comment: As I said: it is not part of the standard library. C89 is no ISO/IEC standard, that would be C90 and neither C90 nor C89 are C standard. That is only C11. See the forewords of the C99 and C11 documents (or the final drafts which are freely available).

Comment: @Olaf not getting it, what is a standard library if not defined by the C standard?

Comment: @Olaf it is stated in forward section 6 of C11.

Comment: The point is, C90 and C99 are not standard, so they don't define what is part of the C **standard** library.

Comment: Ah, got it. Just read paragraph 6 of the Foreword. I mean the very first clause.

Comment: Olaf's point is that the C99 standard *officially* canceled and replaced the C90 standard, and the C11 standard officially canceled and replaced the C99 standard. As far as ISO is concerned, C11 (formally **ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (E)**) is the only C standard. More realistically, IMHO, it's perfectly reasonable to refer to the older standards as standards, as long as you're aware that they've been superseded. Plenty of compilers still support the older editions of the standard.

Comment: Ok, I see, maybe it is better to refer C11 as the *current* C standard, and C99 and others as the previous ones. :)