# The program is not able to print all the words. I am facing this issue with many program. eg -to compute the frequency of the words

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
      char sen[100];
      int i=0,len;
      printf("Enter a senetence\n");
      scanf("%s",sen);
      len=strlen(sen);
      char ch=sen[i];
      while(i<len){
        if(ch==' '){
            printf("\n");
            i++;
            ch=sen[i];
            continue;
        } //i dont know what is the flaw with the logic.
        printf("%c",ch);
        i++;
        ch=sen[i];
        
      }
      return 0;
}
```

The aim of the program is to print the words of a sentence separately. However, this program is successful in printing only the first word. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Add `printf("sen = \"%s\"\n", sen);` right after the scanf and see what happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanf reads only one word from sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65892940/scanf-reads-only-one-word-from-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

You get just one word as input. You can `scanf` the input like:

```c
scanf("%[^\n]s",sen);
```